# Delete 1-to-1 association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have Person-has-one-Address in Rails. the `has_one` association is set on `Person`, while `belongs_to` is set to `Address`.

I tried to delete this association and this worked:

```
person.address = nil
```

which generated a corresponding `UPDATE` statement.

However, if I try to do the same from the child:

```
address.person = nil
```

I get nothing. I tried to do `address.save` and no SQL was generated. I also tried `address.person_id = nil` and still nothing!

I'm using Rails 5 and heard there's some change that prevents this, just not sure what it is.

Comment: You are correct that Rails 5 enforces referential integrity on `belongs_to` relationships but this question is unclear as to your intention. If you want to delete the address then `person.address.destroy` will do that. If you want to delete the person along with  the address, from the address then `class Person < ApplicationRecord; has_one :address, dependent: :destroy; end` should also work and `address.person.destroy`.

Comment: did you get it working?